# Google Sheet Query Unique IDs

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Currently I have a data set like this where there are repeating Lead IDs:

| Column A | Column E | Column I |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lead ID | Date | Name |
| 1 | 6/1/2023 | Adam |
| 1 | 6/1/2023 | Adam |
| 2 | 6/1/2023 | Adam |
| 2 | 6/3/2023 | Adam |
| 3 | 6/3/2023 | Bob |
| 4 | 6/3/2023 | Bob |
| 5 | 6/3/2023 | Jill |
| 5 | 6/3/2023 | Jill |

With the current Google Sheet QUERY formula I have:

```
=QUERY(RAW!A:Z, "select I, count(A) where E >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/1/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/30/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by I", 1)
```

It seems to return this result which is not what I'm looking for:

| Name | Count Lead ID |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 4 |
| Bob | 2 |
| Jill | 2 |

I'm actually looking for a result like this where I get the count of unique Lead IDs as per name:

| Name | Count Lead ID |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 2 |
| Bob | 2 |
| Jill | 1 |

I have also tried to modify the formula to count(distinct A) but it seems to return errors whenever I do that. Most appreciated if there are any suggestions on how I can achieve this result?

Comment: Please edit your question and share your simple data and the expected output as text not images

Comment: Updated with the text for the data

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two nested QUERY, the first one that fines the Unique values by counting A column and grouping by A,I:

```
=QUERY(RAW!A:I, "select I, A, COUNT(A) where E >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/1/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/30/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by I,A", 1)
```

[image]

And a second one that counts column 2 grouping by column 1:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(RAW!A:I, "select I, A, COUNT(A) where E >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/1/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/30/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by I,A", 1),"SELECT Col1,COUNT(Col2) group by Col1")
```

[image]

PS: another option without QUERY:

```
=MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(I2:I,1)),LAMBDA(name,{name,COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A:A,I:I,name,E:E,">="&DATEVALUE("6/1/2023" ),E:E,"<="&DATEVALUE("6/30/2023"))}))
```